# How do i make a circuit that stores information and then verifies the information?

Tags: microcontroller, memory

I was planning to make a new product. I am a newbie in electronics. I was planning to design a circuit which stores information from a scanner and then verifies the same information. If the information matches with the stored information, it needs to give a logic 0.

I am planning to use an Arduino or an Atmega for the prototype. I can manage the coding stuff. I need help as to how i can connect a EPROM to the circuit and then verify the information?Also, if someone can tell me what is the microcontroller used in actual products?

Comment: The Arduinos use ATmega devices. No one use EPROMs these days.

Comment: @LeonHeller yeah sorry! typo!

Answer (score 1):

> **I need help as to how I can connect a EPROM to the circuit**

You probably mean [EEPROM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EEPROM) not [EPROM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EPROM) - the former is Electrically Erasible, the latter typically UV erasible.

Arduinos have microcontrollers that have [in-built EEPROM](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/EEPROM).

That family of microcontrollers has many variants with varying amounts of on-board EEPROM.

If you need a lot of non-volatile memory, there are several ways of [linking external EEPROM](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/SPIEEPROM)

> **and then verify the information?**

I'd use the EEPROM libraries described in the links above.

> **Also, if someone can tell me what is the microcontroller used in actual products?**

The various microcontrollers used in Arduinos are also used in mass-produced commercial products. For example the ATMega328. There are of course many thousands of different microcontrollers. A desgner will choose one that suits the product, probably starting their search with a microcontroller family that is familiar to them or to their company.

It is certainly possible to prototype with a DIP version of a microcontroller and then design with the same IC in a SMD package for larger production runs. There is also no reason why you couldn't prototype many types of product with an Arduino - after all it's just a commonplace type of prototyping/experimenter PCB that has become popular with hobbyists. Then design a cheaper-to-produce custom PCB based on the prototyped circuit and using SMD parts.

Comment: Arduino MCUs don't have EPROMs!

Comment: @Leon: My mistake. Updated to clarify.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick so basically i can simply get an atmega and design a pcb accordingly. and if at all any company likes my product, they may modify the design  accordingly? and also, i searched online but didnt get a sure shot information about this- does arduino uno support external eeprom memory?